# Javascript Regex - 9-digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a variable contains a 9-digit number in Javascript.  This should be basic but for some reason this is failing:

```
    var test = "123123123";
    var pattern = new RegExp("/\d{9}/");

    if(test.match(pattern))
    {
        //This code never executes
    }
    else
    {
        //This code is always executing
        alert('no match!'); 
    }
```

Can anyone see why I am not getting a match?

I also tried type-casting test to an integer with:

```
test = Number(test);
```

...but this doesn't work as it has to be a String to support the .match method.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp - This doesn't put the regex in double quotes like you have.  It also has a `g` after the final `/`.  I don't know javascript well or if that helps.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're mixing the [two different regex constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression). Pick one:

```
 var pattern = new RegExp("^\\d{9}$");
 // or
 var pattern = /^\d{9}$/;
```

**N.B.** you probably want to add start and end anchors (as above) to make sure the *whole* string matches.

Comment: In the RegExp constructor that backslash needs to be escaped to `\\d`.

Comment: Thanks Matt - that's a clear explanation and the link really helped.  The article said a literal is best practice for a fixed pattern which this is - so I'll go with that!  Cheers

Answer (score 11):

You are mixing [regex literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the RegExp class. Try:

```
var test = "123123123";
var pattern = /\d{9}/;

if(test.match(pattern))
{
    alert('match!');
    //This code never executes
}
else
{
    //This code is always executing
    alert('no match!'); 
}​
```

Additionally, you may want to change your regex to match on the beginning and end of line if you want to ensure it contains *only* a 9 digit number. Right now the regex will match any string that contains a 9 digit number. You would change it like so:

```
var pattern = /^\d{9}$/;
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it - I see the difference now!

Answer (score 5):

When using a `new Regexp()` constructor, you should not include the `/` delimieters, since they are treated as literals in the expression.

Also your expression should be anchored `^$` to ensure it contains no other characters than the nine digits.

```
var test = "123123123";
// \d would need to be escaped as \\d in RegExp()
var pattern = new RegExp("^\\d{9}$");
// ..Or...
var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}$");
```

Using a regular expression literal without `new Regexp()` is often a better strategy if you don't need to do string manipulations or include variables in the regex, since it avoids the extra backslash-escaping.

```
var pattern = /^\d{9}$/;
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it - I see the difference now!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't looking for 9 consecutive digits, you are looking for 9 consecutive digits *enclosed in slashes*.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the slashes and escaping the backslash:

```
var test = "123123123";
var pattern = new RegExp("\\d{9}");

if(test.match(pattern))
{
    //This code never executes
    alert("match");
}
else
{
    //This code is always executing
    alert('no match!');
}
```